# Write a program that swaps values within an array

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, swap

**This is for homework**

Here is my program

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap (int *a  , int *b  , int *c  ,  int *d  ,  int *e ) {
    int temp1 = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp1;

    int temp2 = b;
    c = d;
    d = temp2;

    int temp3 = e
    e = a;
    a = temp3;
}

void swap (int *a  , int *b  , int *c  , int *d  , int *e );
int main(void)
{
    int arr[15] = {0};
    int i;
    int a = arr[0], b = arr[7], c = arr[8], d = arr[3], e = arr[14];

    printf("Enter 15 integers\n");
    for(i = 0; i < 15; ++i) {
        scanf("%d" , &arr[i]);
        //printf("The ints are %d " , arr[i]); checked if all the ints were recorded
    }
    swap(a, b, c, d, e);
    printf("Swapped array:\n %d" , arr[i]);

    return 0;
 }
```

So The program is asking me to have the user enter 15 integers. The function would have to swap the 1st integer entered (arr[0]) with the seventh integer entered (arr[7]). Then swap the 8th with the 3rd, then swap the last one with the first. My program complies but gives a handful of warnings and when I try to print my swapped array, all I get is a value of 0. Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit**

Sorry I heard from someone to not worry about the warnings- counter-intuitive to listen. The warnings are:

**[In the function]**

assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

**In main**

passing argument [numbers] of swap makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: These warnings are telling you something, right?

Comment: Seventh integer would be `arr[6]`.

Comment: If your program “gives a handful of warnings”, you should read those warnings and try to address them, or at least post them here. The compiler is trying to tell you something, and usually it’s worth listening.

Comment: `a` is declared as `int` but `swap` expects `int *a`

Comment: @EugeneSh. most of the warnings say something like initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast

Comment: Yes. You passed in pointers. So work with pointers. Not literal int. else use *prefix to copy what the pointer is pointing to. But I think your task here is to swap what each pointer is pointing to.

Comment: @Barmar That would also swap the values in variables only, but then OP prints from the array where the values haven't been swapped.

Comment: Small point: declaring the prototype for `swap()` *after* its implementation is unnecessary. The prototype is intended as a *forward* reference.

Comment: As mentioned you are going from a pointer to a int. the temp variable should be a int * pointer.

Comment: @chrisHG That sort of thing is *very important*, and honestly should be an error. You *cannot* dismiss it as “a handful of warnings” if you want working code. If you ask for help here, you should copy at least one of those warnings *in full*, including the part that talks about where in the source code the problem is.

Comment: I edited my post with the warnings sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several problems with your code.

First, the `swap` function doesn't work. You're swapping the values of the pointers that are local variables inside the function, you're not swapping the array elements they point to. You need to indirect through pointers to get the values.

```
int temp1 = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp1;
```

And similar for all the other pairs you're swapping.

Second, `swap` expects pointers as arguments, but you're passing `int` variables from `main()`. You need to use pointer variables, which you set to the addresses of the array elements:

```
int *a = &arr[0], *b = &arr[7], *c = &arr[8], *d = &arr[3], *e = &arr[14];
```

You might consider changing the `swap()` function so it just takes two pointers, and call it 3 times to do all 3 swaps.

Finally, to print the array, you need to print the elements in a loop:

```
printf("Swapped array: ");
for (i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Another, albeit lesser issue, is that the seventh element of the array is `arr[6]`, not `arr[7]`. Similarly, eighth element is `arr[7]`, and third is `arr[2]`.

Comment: @Barmar , thank you - that got rid of all my warnings, but my swapped array is still only giving me 0.

Comment: You need to print the array values in a loop.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the help!!!